# git attempting to merge an old master into my branch

Tags: git

I recently attempted to merge the latest master into my feature branch, but it seems to have attempted to merge a very old master snapshot. I did the following steps in order:

```
 1. git checkout master
 2. git pull --rebase (I saw all the changes come down)
 3. git checkout my-feature-branch
 4. git merge master
```

however, when I attempt to do `git merge origin/master` it's merging the correct, up-to-date master in. Not sure why this is, does a pull with the --rebase option do something different?

Comment: *Does a pull with `--rebase` do something different?* Yes: `git pull` runs two commands: `git fetch`, then a second command. The second command is `git merge` by default, but is `git rebase` instead of `git merge` if you use `git pull --rebase`. Merge and rebase are very different. There is one case (not all that uncommon) where the difference winds up making no difference, but clearly this wasn't that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `pull --rebase` would replay the local master commits (ie commits done on master branch but not yet pushed) on top of the updated (fetched) `origin/master`.

Check `git status` and `git log --decorate --oneline --graph --all --branches` to check that master does have all the commits expected.

Then, and only then you can proceed.